# Receive real referrer IP but not client IP in PHP

Tags: php, iframe, ip, ip-address, referrer

Lets assume that we have some intermediate site page with iframe, some remote user visit this site and loads my page in this iframe. Can I somehow detect IP address of that intermediate site, but not IP of the user machine in PHP?

So I want to detect referrer IP but not client IP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the browser sends a `referer` header then you can use that to capture the URL of the page containing the iframe element, extract the hostname from it, and then perform a DNS lookup on that hostname.

There are many situations where the browser won't send the `referer` header though, and in those cases you will be out of luck.

Comment: Yes :) That's why I want to receive referrer IP and detect domain by it and compare what we received and what we have in referrer or detect some referrer when it's empty.

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko — The `referer` header is the only information you have. There is no other way to get that information to have something to compare it to.